# Forecasting methods to work globally on a series of datasets

Tags: time-series, forecasting, exponential-smoothing, bagging

Forecasting a numeric time-series is providing an estimator $\hat y(t+1)$ of $y(t+1)$ computed from $(y(1),y(2)...y(t))$. You want it to be close to $y(t+1)$ (say in terms of squared distance).

Now instead of just a numeric value, assume $Y(t)$ is a full dataset with several categorical features. It can be seen as a bag since order does not matter. You want to provide an estimator $\hat Y(t+1)$ of $Y(t+1)$ that is statistically close to $Y(t+1)$.

Datasets $A$ and $B$ being statistically close means something a bit vague. I can give a sketch of a definition. Let $F$ be a condition on the features like for example "feature1=1 and feature2=5". Call $F_A$ and $F_B$ the number of elements satisfying $F$ in $A$ and $B$ respectively. $A$ and $B$ are said to be close if $F_A$ and $F_B$ are close for all $F$ as long $F$ is not restrictive enough to match a very small number of elements where difference would be essentially caused by random. A sort of measure of statistically significative distance.

It is possible to implement a bag-wise exponential smoothing (a simple forecasting method) for bags directly. Define $\hat Y(t+1)=(1-\alpha)\hat Y(t)+\alpha Y(t)$ where multiplication stands for taking a random sample ($aX$ means: the dataset resulting of keeping each element of $X$ with probability $a$ with independent trials) and + stands for concatenation (union on bags).

Are there known advanced forecast methods for datasets that extend some time-series methods, typically dealing with seasonality or trend?

Comment: How do you multiply a "bag" $Y_t$ by a scalar $\alpha$? I see how this would work for a *vector* (componentwise), but not for an unordered "bag". Plus, are the component "features" actually numeric, or can they also be categorical?

Comment: Could you make your title more informative?

Comment: @Stephan: I'm mainly working with categorical features. I made the definition of multiplication more explicit.

Comment: Your notating $\alpha X$ reminds me of [thinning operators](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/cqd/files/Mixed%20thinning.pdf).